# User Profile Names and Sizes into CSV File

Tags: powershell, csv, export-csv

This script gets user profiles on a machine and I am able to provide the output into a text file but I cannot figure out how to export this information to a CSV file.

```
dir C:\Users | foreach -Begin {} -Process {
    $size = (dir $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object ‘length’ -Sum -Maximum).Sum
    Write-Output ("{0:n2}" -f ($size/1MB) + " MB", $_.FullName) >> "C:\scripts\UserProfiles\UserProfiles.txt"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create an object with properties and then use `Export-Csv`

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users |
    ForEach-Object `
        -Begin { Write-Host -Object "Scanning user directories" } `
        -Process {
            Write-Host "Scanning path '$($_.FullName)'"
            $Size = (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object ‘length’ -Sum -Maximum).Sum

            [pscustomobject] @{
                Name = $_.Name
                Path = $_.FullName
                Size = '{0:N2} MB' -f ( $Size / 1MB )
            }
        } |
        Export-Csv -Path C:\Scripts\UserProfiles\UserProfiles.csv -NoTypeInformation
```